# How to use secret values stored in secret manager?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am creating access key and secret key using terraform and storing it in secret value in secret manager, how to retrieve and use those access and secret key values stored in secret manager in terraform code?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62329059/10846194) answer your query?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to retrieve a secret in terraform from aws secret manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62328683/how-to-retrieve-a-secret-in-terraform-from-aws-secret-manager)

Comment: I manually stored access key and secret key in secrets manager, is their any way to call those values into the terraform code for execution instead of declaring it manually in terraform? because calling those values from arn and secret name is not working in case of secret key and access key.